# Hooking up kb+mouse via aorus gigabyte fv43u to PC and laptop

Tags: display, kvm-switch, multiple-computers

I have bought aorus gigabyte fv43u monitor that features a kvm switch. It has 2 usb 3 type A downstream ports and 1 usb 3 type B upstream port. I have a stationary PC and laptop that I would like to use one keyboard and mouse for (control one system at a time). It will be very hard for me to keep reaching down to switch the upstream from PC to laptop over and over (my PC is on the floor with back facing into the wall). What are my options? The page for the monitor says it has KVM switch built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual explains it, although it's not very clear.

You have to connect each computer with a separate upstream USB and video cables. That's 4 cables in total (2 per computer) or 3 cables total if using USB type C for video and USB combined.

For USB connections use the type C port and the type B port next to it. For video connections I think you can use any combination of ports, although the manual isn't clear about this.

Almost done, except the monitor doesn't know which video inputs and USB upstreams are connected to the same computer. In the monitor's OSD menu select *Display » KVM* and use *KVM Wizard* to associate upstream USB ports with corresponding video inputs.

Finally, you can assign KVM switching to one of the hotkeys of the monitor.

Comment: Thank you! I'll go pick up a usb-c cable to see if KVM will work like that. Will come back with the results.

Comment: Note that you need type C on both ends of the cable and a computer with DP alt mode support to transmit video through the same cable.

Comment: I was thinking about type c cable only for input, but I guess I will take the time to find the right one to not mess with too many cables. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Tested it with thunderbolt 4 cable, works to hookup everything (displayport, kb, mouse).